# Condition of a unitary matrix

Tags: matrices

If a square matrix $\mathbf{A}$ satisfies $\mathbf{A}^{H}\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{I}$, then is it a unitary matrix? Or, is there a counter example with $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{H}\neq\mathbf{I}$?

Comment: If A has a left inverse then it is also the right inverse for any square matrix A.

Comment: You can find the proof of the above fact here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172872/short-matrix-algebra-question/172897#172897

Comment: We should add that the left inverse and right inverse are equal (if one exists), which is really the question posed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $A^HA=I$ we know that $A^H = A^{-1}$ (from the definition of an inverse). If we multiply on both sides with $A$ we have 
$$A A^H = A A^{-1}=I$$